# patterns.web module: See if immediate parent has a certain string

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I'm using the [patterns web mining module](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern) in python. I am attempting to scrape some values and I'm wondering if it's possible to check if just the immediate parent has a certain attribute, not all parents (inc grandparents, etc).

In the picture below, is it possible to only check if  which is the parent of  has some attribute? when I use val.parent, I get a lot more than just . I am trying to grab the name 'VICTOR ODZAU'.

Another potential way to ask this question is more open-endedly. Is there a more efficient way to grab the name VICTOR ODZAU?

```
dom = web.Element(req.text)
    for i, val in enumerate(dom.by_tag("td")):
    print val.parent.content
    if 'Name' in val.parent.content.encode('ascii','ignore'):
         val.content
```

[image: Example of html]

UPDATE:

I figured it out. it turns out that the parent function does grab immediate parents, but there are quirks when the tree is more complicated.

Comment: `requests` only loads the URL for you, it doesn't parse the HTML. URLs can lead to all sorts of data, not just HTML. Are you using an HTML parser?

Comment: `val.parent` suggests you are; but both `lxml` and BeautifulSoup support such an attribute on the element tree they provide after parsing.

Comment: what would the specific function be called in beautiful soup?

Comment: Where does `web.Element()` come from? What library are you using (apart from `requests`)?

Comment: it comes from the pattern module

Comment: Sorry, what is the pattern module here?

Comment: https://github.com/clips/pattern